# Enable sharing on printer and set sharename

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript

Does anyone know a script that sets sharing on a local printer and sets the share name to the name of the printer itself? The OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1

I already got this:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject( _
    "winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Printer")
For Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
 If objPrinter.Shared = "False" Then
    ObjPrinter.Shared = "True"
    ObjPrinter.ShareName = "objPrinter.Name"
 End If
Next
```

But I don't know how parse the printername into the ObjPrinter.ShareName. I would like a Powershell or VBScript. The script doesn't seem to be working in this way. Hopefully someone is able to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just have to remove the quotes around `True`, `False`, and `objPrinter.Name` and use `Put_` to save the changes. I also would recommend to add error handling, because no every type of printer can be shared. The resulting code would look like this:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject( _
    "winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Printer")
For Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
 If objPrinter.Shared = False Then
     objPrinter.Shared = True
     objPrinter.ShareName = objPrinter.Name

     On Error Resume Next
     objPrinter.Put_
     msg = Err.Description
     On Error GoTo 0
     If msg <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Cannot share " & objPrinter.Name & ": " & msg
     End If
 End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell to enable or disable sharing on Printers
http://winplat.net/2015/12/04/powershell-to-share-and-unshared-the-printers/

### To share a printer

```
Set-Printer -Name DummyPrinter -Shared $True -Published $True -ShareName MyDummyPrinter
```

### To share a printer on remote computer

```
Set-Printer -Name DummyPrinter -Shared $True -Published $True -ShareName MyDummyPrinter -ComuterName PrintSvr01
```

Where,
`DummyPrinter` is the name of the print queue,
`MyDummyPrinter` is the desired shared name and
`PrintSvr01` is the remote server that hosts the printer.

Please note, the parameter `-Publish` enabled the option ‘List in Directory’. You can omit if you do not want the option.

### Multiple Printers?

`get-printer -ComputerName PrintSvr01 | foreach{Set-Printer -name $_.name -Shared $true -ShareName $_.name -Published $true -ComputerName PrintSvr01}`

### To unshare a printer

To unshare, set the –Shared parameter to $False
`Set-Printer -Name DummyPrinter -Shared $True -ComuterName PrintSvr01`